incorrect expansion of template handlebars.js
I can't figure out how handlebars performs template generation.
I found one case that gives me unwanted results. It seems that handlebars behaves differently depending on the template to be expanded.
Below is an example with the code I ran.
First: preparing the data and running the template is done like this:
<script type="text/JavaScript">
        function showNumbers() {
            var jsondata='[{"number":"one"},{"number":"two"}]'; //the data
            var data=JSON.parse(jsondata);

            var source = $("#listNumbers").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var html = template({items:data});

            $("#numbers").html(html);
        }
</script>


The first template to expand that works as expected (it is very simple)
source:
<script id="listNumbers" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ol>
        {{#items}}
            <li>
                <div>number {{number}}</div>
            </li>
        {{/items}}
    </ol>
</script>

epanded

<div id="numbers">
    <ol>
       <li>
           <div>number one</div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <div>number two</div>
       </li>
    </ol>
</div>


Correct!!
Now to the template I simply added a div to put a title above and the number below.
code:
<script id="listNumbers" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ol>
        {{#items}}
            <li>
                <div>number is</div>
                <div>{{number}}</div>
            </li>
        {{/items}}
    </ol>
</script>

expanded:
<div id="numbers">
    <ol>
        <li>
           ** <div>number is
                  <div>one</div>
            </div>**
        </li>
        <li>
           ** <div>number is
                 <div>two</div>
            </div>**
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

NOT CORRECT!!
In this case the template expanded incorrectly by putting one div inside the other!
The resulting HTML is invalid and the page is displayed incorrectly.
I have done several tests with more structured HTML and they all expand badly.
Surely I am missing something but I can't see it.

Handlebars is a mature project and I don't believe it has the issues you are describing. Here is a fiddle that uses the template you shared and it produces the expected result. I suspect there is something invalid about the HTML in your template - perhaps a missing closing tag somewhere.
